# Guidance needed with 'class' task (beginner)

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

It looks daunting, but please bear with me, it's not as difficult as it looks. I have a code here about beam deflection. It's just some maths and numbers at this point. Only the last part requires attention.

```
class beam(object):
"""This class is models the deflection of a simply supported beam under
multiple point loads, following Euler-Bernoulli theory and the principle of
superposition.
"""

    def __init__(self, E, I, L):
        """The class costructor.
        """
        self.E = 8.0E9  # Young's modulus of the beam in N/m^2
        self.I = 1.333E-4  # Second moment of area of the beam in m^4
        self.L = 5.0  # Length of the beam in m
        self.Loads = [(0.0, 0.0)]  # the list of loads applied to the beam
        self.name = "beam"

    def setLoads(self, Loads):
        '''This function allows multiple point loads to be applied to the beam
        using a list of tuples of the form (load, position)
        '''
        self.Loads = Loads
```

The "def __ init __" and "def setLoads" were given, so the above doesn't need changing. I inputted values for self.E, I and L since I thought I needed them there, but those numbers can be replaced back to the letters that they were before.

```
    def beamDeflection(self, Load, x):
        """Just a simple calculation, really.
        """
        E = 8.09 * (10 ** 9)
        I = 1.333 * (10 ** -4)
        L = 5
        a = 2.5
        b = a + (x - a)
        (P1, a) = Load
        if 0 <= x <= 2.5:
            beamDeflection = ((P1*b*x)/(6*L*E*I))*((L**2)-(x**2)-(b**2))
        else:
            if 2.5 < x <= 5:
                beamDeflection = ((P1*b)/(6*L*E*I)) / (((L/b)*((x-a)**3)) -
                                                       (x**3) + (x*((L**2) -
                                                                 (b**2))))
        return beamDeflection
```

The above "beamDeflection" is the simple code I typed up that just calculates deflection in a beam using a formula that's already been given. Essentially, if a weight is put on the left side of the beam, it'll calculate a number out and the same for the other side.

```
    def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
        """The function getTotalDeflection(self, x) should go through each load tuple in the
        list.Loads and calculate the beam deflection at point x (Hint: the function you just 
        created could be handy here!). getTotalDeflection should return the total deflection at x, 
        which is the sum over each of the individual deflections.
        """
```

My understanding is that I need to a "for" loop to go through each load tuple while involving the self.load. I'm not sure on how to go about combining both of those things together. If anyone can help me out, I'd really, really appreciate it.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question was not horrible for a new user. The problem statement is quite clear and it includes a small bit of own ideas for the solution. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably this (else please clarify):

```
def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
    return sum(self.beamDeflection(loadval, x) for loadval in self.Loads)
```

Comment: You beat me in speed and style. :) +1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help as well :) I understand that it's a simple return statement, but "beamDeflection" is not defined for some reason. Edit: Actually, I removed the indents to the left of my "def" and the warning sign appears to have gone now.

Comment: @tablue it should be defined if it is in the same class. looking at your code, everything  after `class beam(object):` seems to lack one level of indentation.

Comment: Ahh, yes, everything is lacking a level of indent. I think I'll try and figure this one out myself though. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I just tried running the code and it says that beamDeflection takes 3 arguments, but only 2 are given, so do I just type "self" as the first argument?

Comment: @tablue try again with `self.beamDeflection(loadval, x)`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
  total = 0
  # For every load in `Loads`
  for load in self.Loads:
    # Compute the deflection and add it to the total
    total += self.beamDeflection(load, x):
  return total
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) Your method looks a little bit familiar, but for the "total += ....", I'm getting an invalid syntax. I think it might be to do with the "load" since it's a tuple [(P1, a) = Load] but I'm not sure on how to fix it, if it's even the error.

Comment: @tablue I forgot to add `self.` in front of the method to call it. Should work now. The other answer is more pythonic, though. Glad it works now!